# linux script to kill java process

Tags: linux, bash, kill-process

I want linux script to kill java program running on console.

Following is the process running as jar.

```
[rapp@s1-dlap0 ~]$ ps -ef |grep java
rapp    9473    1  0 15:03 pts/1    00:00:15 java -jar wskInterface-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar
rapp   10177  8995  0 16:00 pts/1    00:00:00 grep java
[rapp@s1-dlap0 ~]$
```

Comment: does `pkill java` count?

Answer (score 113, accepted):

You can simply use `pkill -f` like this:

```
pkill -f 'java -jar'
```

**EDIT:** To kill a particular java process running your specific jar use this regex based pkill command:

```
pkill -f 'java.*lnwskInterface'
```

Comment: Yes you can add jar name as well.

Comment: now my jar in ps looks like rcapp   23671     1 16 11:23 pts/0    00:00:03 /usr/java/jdk1.6.0_37//bin/java -Xmx2048m -Drdc.log.file=/home/rapp/apps/LNWSKInterface/logs/dev.log -jar /home/rapp/apps/LNWSKInterface/jar/lnwskInterface.jar and if i do pkill -f 'java -jar' it does not work. can i use wild card like as follows pkill -f 'java *-jar' ?

Comment: You can use: `pgrep -if 'java .*-jar'`

Comment: but when i tried pkill -f pgrep -f 'java .*-jar' it didn't work... gives help option

Comment: You can simply do: `kill $(pgrep -f 'java .*-jar')`

Comment: this also works kill -9 `ps -ef | pgrep -f 'java .*-jar'` but i like  'anubhava's ans it is simple.

Comment: i am sorry but my jar name is 'lnwskInterface' and there may be more then one jars running i want to kill only my jar i tried "kill $(pgrep -f 'java .*lnwskInterface-jar')" can you help me pls

Comment: I don't get what's the problem, even `pkill -f 'java.*lnwskInterface'` should work.

Comment: you are very helpful i am grateful to you, have one more last question i have export variable $app=lnwskInterface when i tried pkill -f 'java.*$app' didn't work out. thanks for help in advance

Comment: try double quotes instead like this: `pkill -f "java.*$app"`

Comment: @anubhava - I'm killing java process using shell_exec('kill -9 $pid') but I want to set time limit here like this, $pid process should be killed automatically after 1 minute. So, how can I set this time constraint here??

Comment: You can probably use: `sleep 60; kill -9 $pid`

Comment: pkill -f 'java -jar nameSpecific.jar'

Comment: How is it different from `pkill java`?

Answer (score 44):

If you just want to kill any/all java processes, then all you need is;

```
killall java
```

If, however, you want to kill the **wskInterface** process in particular, then you're most of the way there, you just need to strip out the process id;

```
PID=`ps -ef | grep wskInterface | awk '{ print $2 }'`
kill -9 $PID
```

Should do it, there is probably an easier way though...

Comment: I'm always amazed to see `grep`s piped into `awk`s!!! Shall we call this Useless Use Of Grep? Anyways, it's much better to use `pkill` with the `-f` option as anubhava mentioned (if you have `pkill` installed of course, and if it has the `-f` option).

Comment: I tried "PID=`ps -ef | grep wskInterface | awk '{ print $2 }'`
kill -9 $PID" 
and found -bash: kill: (10395) - No such process. it actually killed the process but also give the error

Comment: @Faisalkhan That's because you tried to kill the `ps` process itself... `:-(`. Don't use this method, use anubhava's instead.

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf I find grep to be a little easier when it comes to filtering out lines. And yep, I knew this method was a little off when I typed it, but it should work. And it's beardy, which I enjoy.

Comment: `ps -ef | grep wskInterface | grep -v grep | awk '{ print $2 }'` ignores your own grep command.

Answer (score 5):

if there are multiple java processes and you wish to kill them with one command
try the below command

```
kill -9 $(ps -ef | pgrep -f "java")
```

replace "java" with any process string identifier , to kill anything else.

Answer (score 1):

Use [jps](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/share/jps.html) to list running java processes. The command returns the process id along with the main class. You can use kill command to kill the process with the returned id or use following one liner script.

```
kill $(jps | grep <MainClass> | awk '{print $1}')
```

MainClass is a class in your running java program which contains the main method.

Comment: @Xerus Try kill `$(jps -l | grep <fully.qualified.ClassName> | awk '{print $1}')`

Comment: the issue seems to be the grep. Either of your suggestions only work once I take out the grep

Answer (score 1):

pkill -f for whatever reason does not work for me. Whatever that does, it seems very finicky about actually grepping through what ps aux shows me clearly is there.

After an afternoon of swearing I went for putting the following in my start script:

`(ps aux | grep -v -e 'grep ' | grep MainApp | tr -s " " | cut -d " " -f 2 | xargs kill -9 ) || true`