# Process for switching a puppet module installed from the forge

Tags: puppet

I've installed:

```
puppet module uninstall branan/minecraft
```

and used:

```
class { 'minecraft': }
```

a module from the forge. This module in particular installs and configures a minecraft server, but the problem i'm having relates to all modules really.

So, after provisioning, the server now has a new service running as well as all the minecraft files stored in /opt/minecraft.

The day has come where I'd like to try out a new minecraft module, as it's meant to allow more customisations, is easier to use etc..

How would I go about switching the modules over? It seems to me I'd need to do something like:

1. Somehow revert all the changes made by the current module, e.g. `class {'minecraft': ensure => purged }`?
2. Run puppet apply to apply the changes...
3. Run `puppet module uninstall branan/minecraft --modulepath puppet/forge-modules`
4. Install the new module
5. Add the new class, with the advanced configuration options e.g. `class {'minecraft': heap_size => '1024M' }`
6. Run puppet apply again...

This seems quite a long and manual process, involving two puppet applys and a minecraft server which is down until the last step.

I don't think `class {'minecraft': ensure => purged }` would even work, the module, as far as I can see, has no code in which to remove the files or the service it's created.

As you can see, i'm quite confused and i'm probably missing something obvious. Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean by new minecraft module? Is it a new version or a different module?

Comment: It's a different module. Switching from https://forge.puppetlabs.com/branan/minecraft to https://forge.puppetlabs.com/civilfritz/minecraft

Answer (score 1):

You mostly have the steps right.

The `ensure` parameter greatly depends on how the class is using it, however. As far as I can tell, the `ensure` parameter is hardcoded.

The author has not written his module in a way that allows for uninstallation, compared to the new module, which accepts an `ensure` parameter.

Your best bet would be to halt the service manually - either through the command line or with puppet (untested).

**Command Line**: Adapted from [linux script to kill java process](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13711855/linux-script-to-kill-java-process)

```
ps -ef | grep minecraft
```

Note the id

```
kill 1234
```

Where 1234 is the id of the running instance of minecraft.

**Puppet**: In theory, this should work as you have access to the classes that the module provides, as well. I have not tried it out personally myself.

```
service { 'minecraft':
    ensure => stopped
}
```

Lastly, you may or may not want to remove the config files. They all seem to be located under the minecraft home directory, which is under `/opt/minecraft` by default. These won't affect the new module as the new module would either overwrite them or use a separate directory for its configs.

Then you can uninstall the old module, and install the new module

In general, applying the puppet scripts shouldn't take too long, no longer than a minute each.